# Does notifying a condition variable guarantee the wake-up of a thread with a successful condition/predicate if one exists?

Tags: c++, concurrency, synchronization, c++20, condition-variable

The information I've found on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) is vague in this regard, so I'm asking here. Say I have two threads waiting on a condition with one having a true predicate, and the other a false one (e.g. `condition.wait(lock, [=]{ return some_condition; }`). The main thread decides to randomly notify one of them with `cond.notify_one()`.

Assume that the waiting thread selected is the one where the predicate is false. Is the thread going to implicitly notify the next one (if there are any left), or will it be doomed to wait until spurious wakeup?

In case only a single thread is woken up no matter whether its condition succeeds or fails, what would be a good way for the first thread to try waking the next one up for a guaranteed successful notify? A naive fix:

```cpp
condition.wait(lock, [=] {
    if (!some_condition) condition.notify_one();
    return some_condition;
});
```

Other than pessimization, the "notify wave" may notify the same threads repeatedly which is ineffective + never halt in case no threads have successful predicates. A `notify_all()` won't work, because we may accidentally end waking up multiple threads that satisfy the condition, meanwhile we only want a single one to go through at most.

Comment: There is no guarantee made regarding which thread is notified, regardless of which thread is doing the notification. Arguably if both threads get notified by the same cv, but both or either may be able to do useful work, then both should be notified (notify all). I generally strive for one "condition" per condition variable. It's easier to reason about.

Comment: "*The main thread decides to randomly notify one of them with cond.notify_one().*" If more than one thread waits on a condition, you shouldn't use `notify_one`.

Comment: @NicolBolas There are multiple waiting, but I'm looking to only awaken a single one at a time, which will during its lock-holding period make the predicate false for all the other waiting threads, and then make it true for some of the threads again at the end of the critical section. I'd use a semaphore, but only a certain type of thread may access the critical section at any given time.

Comment: @MarkedasDuplicate: "*which will during its lock-holding period make the predicate false for all the other waiting threads, and then make it true for some of the threads again at the end of the critical section.*" That's called "locking a mutex". You don't need to change the condition at all in order to do this.

Comment: @NicolBolas What I need is a conditional mutex, then. There's `n+m` threads waiting, and when the lock unlocks I sometimes want only a thread of either `n` or `m` type to be able to lock it and do its work. At other times, both `n` and `m` will do.

Comment: @MarkedasDuplicate: This all sounds to me like you need a task scheduling system, not a condition variable. One where you can order tasks to be executed based on whether they are in group n or group m.

Comment: I think it's a bit strange for different threads to have different conditions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Something like it, probably. I was just seeking a potential clean solution to the sudden challenge I had with my current approach before considering a more macro-level change to the design overall. Task queues won't really do for my case, but since the answer to my initial question seems to be "not possible", I'll know how to keep looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A notify_all() won't work, because we may accidentally end waking up
> multiple threads that satisfy the condition, meanwhile we only want a
> single one to go through at most.

That is not entirely accurate. Only one thread can lock a given mutex at a time, no matter what. If all execution threads who are waiting on the condition variable locked the same mutex (as they should) before they started to wait on the condition variable, then only one of those execution threads will successfully re-lock the mutex and "wake up", and return from `wait()`. When it unlocks the mutex the next scheduled execution thread will be able to re-lock it and return from its `wait()`. And so on. `notify_all()` does not result in all execution threads galloping forward, full speed ahead. Effectively only one thread gets woken up, at a time, because they all must re-lock the same mutex. This single-threads them.

All execution threads get ***scheduled*** to be woken up by `notify_all`, and they will all get woken up. However, effectively, only one execution thread will end up woken first, and lock the mutex. When it unlocks the mutex the next execution thread, that got scheduled to be woken up by `notify_all()`, will be able to re-lock it, and so on.

Next, let's look at what `wait()` with a predicate [is logically equivalent to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait):

```
while (!stop_waiting()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

Note that the predicate, here named `stop_waiting` is checked ***while the mutex is locked***, and it is checked only after the "real" `wait()`, the one that doesn't check the predicate condition, returns.

Therefore, the solution to your problem is simpler than you think:

1. Use `notify_all()`.
2. Whichever thread succeeds in returning from `wait()` simply needs to do whatever is needed so that the predicate condition is no longer satisfied. The exact manner of doing so depends on the predicate.

So, in the end, one of the execution threads will get woken up, and it will "turn off" the predicate condition. After this execution thread unlocks the mutex, all the other ones will wake up, but the predicate condition is no longer met. The End.

Comment: "**All execution threads get scheduled to be woken up by notify_all, and they will all get woken up. However, effectively, only one execution thread will end up woken first, and lock the mutex**": What exactly differs here compared to waking up a single thread via `notify_one()`? It seems to be counter-intuitive to call `notify_all()` in case one or more threads are blocked, when there is only going to be one single thread locking the mutex and continuing execution in the end.

Comment: `notify_all` guarantees that all threads will be waken up. Now, the threads get waken up, as explained, only one at a time, but they will all be waken up, one after another. `notify_one` only wakes up one randomly-chosen execution thread.

Comment: That's how I understood it as well. However, in the end, only one of those threads can claim the lock, while all other threads have to wait again until the lock is released. My question was, do I really need to call `notify_all()`? Since you have to call it (assuming no new threads are claiming the lock in the meantime or in the future) N times for N threads waiting to claim the lock, why not call `notify_one()` N times until all threads got their turn? I'm just asking because I don't know of any situation where `notify_all()` should be used instead of `notify_one()` or vice versa.

Comment: Whether or not `notify_one` or `notify_all` is required depends entirely on each individual circumstance. If, after successfully locking the mutex, the execution thread goes about its business before unlocking the mutex: if it can leave things in a state where the condition expression ***still*** evaluates to true, then `notify_all` is required, so that the next thread in the list of all threads, that were originally scheduled to wake up, will wake up and will successfully relock the mutex. Otherwise, they'll remain blissfully asleep and unaware that they are eligible to lock the mutex.

Comment: Thanks you for the elaborate comment, I think I finally know what my misunderstanding was. Then, isn't it better to always call `notify_all()`, regardless of how many threads there are?

Comment: If it is guaranteed that 1) every execution thread that is waiting on a mutex uses a condition that will evaluate to true, after `notify_one`, 2) every execution thread that, once woken up by `notify_one` will make the condition evaluate `false` for all other execution threads, then using `notify_one` will be slightly more optimal.

Comment: @CRoemheld If one has multiple identical threads waiting on a condition variable, but only one thread is required to start working, `notify_one()` is more efficient. And if one has multiple different threads with different work profile etc., the optimal solution is usually to use a private condition variable for each of those threads.